# What happens to local code when we try to switch the branch in the sourcetree?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using source tree, and having to branches local and master, when i switch the branch from local to master , and opened the solution using visual studio i found some files were missing , I am not sure what happens to local code when we switch the branches, please help me on this.

Answer (score 7):

When you switch a branch, all files that are under control of Git will be replaced with the state of the new branch. That includes changes to files as well as additions and deletions.

Note that this is a normal Git feature and doesn't have anything to do with Sourcetree (the UI simply executes a `git co` command in the background)

In your case this means that you have some files in your current 'local' branch that simply do not exist in the master. You could get them there by merging your 'local' branch into the master branch.

The files are "hidden" by Git and can be revealed by switching back to your branch.

Answer (score 5):

The changes in your code will be stored in your branch and whenever you switch again to the old branch you can get your codes. 
In general if you want to switch between branch you just commit and merge it with master always.
Hope your problem sloved

Comment: Local branch changes will *only* be stored if committed or stashed, eg. And if they are committed then they *are already stored* before the checkout. This is why git checkout will not proceed (unless forced) if there are files with modifications that would be overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

When git switches branches - or rather, [checks out](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) a branch - it will make the working directory look like the branch 'in the *committed* repository'. It does this by adding/removing/updating local files and directories as needed, *for* files that are tracked/exist<sup>{*checkout-won't-lose-work}</sup> in either branch.

The checkout itself *does not commit any changes*.

If the git checkout would remove or modify a file that has changes (ie. the changes are not committed on the current branch) then the checkout will abort  unless forced. This prevents losing local changes until they can be properly dealt with.

Because of this behavior a checkout is a safe<sup>{*except-when-forced}</sup> operation and can always be reverted: it moves from one commit to another and, in doing so, makes the working directory 'look' like the commit it is moving to.

Thus, to restore the 'missing files', simply checkout the previous branch and they will be re-added to the working directory. (Depending on the goal it may be appropriate to stay in the current branch, browse differences, and merge/restore relevant changes.)

---

<sup>{*checkout-won't-lose-work}</sup> A checkout will leave untracked files alone and will not delete or update them<sup>{*except-when-forced}</sup>.

<sup>{*except-when-forced}</sup> This guarantee is violated if the checkout was erroneously forced and resulted in discarded local changes..